# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String JSON Tokener android

Tags: java, android, json, casting, classcastexception

The following is my code. It works fine on the emulator. But when I run it on my android device, it crashes with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String at the line marked below. I can't find the place where the casting has gone wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
 public static MatrixCursor getRespAsCursor(String query) {
    String url = (String)(API_URL + "?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&" + query);
    System.out.println(url);
    String resp = (String)getAPIResp(url);
    JSONObject reply;
    MatrixCursor emptyCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[0]);

    try {
        reply = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(resp).nextValue();//CRASHES HERE
        String statusCode = (String)reply.getString("statusCode");
        if(!statusCode.equals("200")) {
            return emptyCursor;
        }
        int count = Integer.parseInt(reply.getString("count"));
        if(count < 1) {
            return emptyCursor;
        }

        JSONArray data = reply.getJSONArray("data");

        //Get keys in String[] format
        Iterator<String> keys = data.optJSONObject(0).keys();
        List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Add "_id" as adapters need it for traversal
        copy.add("_id");

        //copy rest of the keys
        while (keys.hasNext())
            copy.add(keys.next());
        String[] sKeys = new String[copy.size()];
        copy.toArray(sKeys);

        int len = data.length();

        //Create Cursor with JSON keys as columns
        MatrixCursor resultCursor = new MatrixCursor(sKeys, len);

        //Add rows to Cursor
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            JSONObject d = data.optJSONObject(i);
            List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for(String key: copy) {
                if(key.equals("_id")) {
                    values.add(Integer.toString(i));
                }
                else {
                    values.add(d.opt(key));
                }
            }
            resultCursor.addRow(values);
        }

        return resultCursor;
    }
    catch(JSONException e) {
        return emptyCursor;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you print the `resp` value to make sure it is a valid `JSON` as you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already shown the place the casting goes wrong - it's here:

```
reply = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(resp).nextValue();
```

`nextValue()` is returning a `String`, and you're casting it to `JSONObject`.

I suspect the JSON isn't as you expect it to be - it's not a `statusCode = "value"` pair; it's just the value.

You should check the JSON that you're returning, and either change to cast to a string, or if you want to be able to handle both forms of JSON, check the result with `instanceof` before casting:

```
Object reply = new JSONTokener(resp).nextValue();
if (reply instanceof String) {
   ...
} else if (reply instanceof JSONObject) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: It returns a JSONObject in case of the emulator but a String in case of the device. Why is that?

Comment: @Namratha: I suspect you're getting different JSON in `resp`. You should look into that first.

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna have a look at [JSONTokener javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue%28%29)

The doc says `nextValue()`

> Get the next value. The value can be a Boolean, Double, Integer,
>   JSONArray, JSONObject, Long, or String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.

You are probably getting the `ClassCastException` as your line of code

```
 reply = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(resp).nextValue();//CRASHES HERE
```

does not return JSONObject.

You might want to check instance type of the returned object before typecasting it. 
For example,

```
Object obj = new JSONTokener(resp).nextValue();
if(obj instanceof JSONObject){
  reply = (JSONObject)obj;
} else {
  //Handle otherwise,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 reply = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(resp).nextValue();//CRASHES HERE
```

If you are getting a `ClassCastException` is because the `Object` returned by `nextValue()` is not a JSONObject (probably a `String` instance)